# JavaScript checkbox checked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Code :

```
var str = '2,4';
var accept_message = str.split(',');


var accept_message_html = '';
var accpet_message_Obj = {
    1: 'Friends',
    2: 'Models',
    3: 'Premiums',
    4: 'Basics'
};
$.each(accpet_message_Obj, function(key, value) {
    accept_message_html += '<span style="padding-right:30px;"><input style="float:none;" type="checkbox" name="privacy_options[]"' + (key == accept_message[key] ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + ' value="' + key + '" /> ' + value + '</span>\n';
});

$('#content-area').html(accept_message_html);
```

Above coding not working. I need to `checkbox` checked which values are `2` and `4` but there is no checkbox selected. :(

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/ab3fLr7c/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/v6br6ydw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if `key` exists in `accept_message`

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

*Code*

```
accept_message.indexOf(key) > -1
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/v6br6ydw/)

However, as [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is supported in IE9+, You can use [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

*Code*

```
$.inArray(key, accept_message) > -1
```